# Google Login Not Allowed Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, security, authentication, google-account

I am running a selenium automation test from a Linux terminal only using the command line(No GUI)

I am getting now an error that says

[image]

If I run this headless on my local mac it works fine. Has anyone experienced this error before?

Comment: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en

Comment: I checked that out and used an app password but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.

I know this is quite a late answer, but logging in to Google is still possible (by exploiting a bypass).

By default, Google detects and effectively blocks all logins from Selenium webdriver.

The following link comes from the Google OAuth Playground, ensuring the practicality of the link. It most likely won't expire any time soon.

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth/oauthchooseaccount?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&prompt=consent&response_type=code&client_id=407408718192.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=email&access_type=offline&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

You can use that link (ie. `driver.get()`) to log into your Google account.

This bypasses the automation checks allows you to log into Google using Selenium. At least for now.

**UPDATE:** As of January 2021, this no longer works.